# Django User Profile Update form returning blank

Tags: django, forms, templates

Form is updating without error but after saving form, all fields are empty.Here is my code:
#models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_jobseeker = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class JobseekerProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True, 
related_name='jobseekerprofile')

# Basic Information
FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='First Name')
LastName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Last Name')
Gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
DateOffBorth = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date Of Birth')
MarrigeStatus = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MARRIED_STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='Marrige 
Status')
Religion = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=RELIGION_CHOOSE)
PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Phone Number')
Email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Email Address')
Nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=NATIONALITY_CHOOSE, verbose_name='Nationality')
CurrentAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Current Address')
PernamentAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Pernament Address')
ProfileImage = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Jobseeker/Profile_Pictures', verbose_name='Profile 
Picture')

# Education Information
Education = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES, verbose_name='Education')
EducationProgram = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Education Program')
EducationBoard = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=EDUCATION_BOARD_CHOICES, 
verbose_name='Education Board')
NameOfInstitute = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name Of Institute')

# skill
MySkill = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, verbose_name='My Skill')

# Past jobs
WorkingExperience = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Working Experience') 
WorkedField = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='Worked Related Fields')  
WorkedCompanyName = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Worked Company Name')
WorkedCompanyWebsite = models.URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Worked Company Website')

# job category
JobCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Job Category')

# add language
Language = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LANGUAGES_CHOICES)

# about Me
AboutMe = RichTextField(verbose_name='About Me')

# Social account
Facebook = models.URLField(max_length=100)
Twitter = models.URLField(max_length=100)
Instagram = models.URLField(max_length=100)

# upload cv
UploadCv = models.FileField(upload_to='Jobseeker/CVs', verbose_name='Upload Your CV')





def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} profile'


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("jobseeker:jobseeker_profile_detail")
```

#Signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from account.models import JobseekerProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch  import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **Kwargs):
    if created:
        JobseekerProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **Kwargs):
    instance.jobseekerprofile.save()
```

#forms.py

```
class JobseekerSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_jobseeker = True
        user.save()
        return user


class JobseekerUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ['username']


class JobseekerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = JobseekerProfile
    fields = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email','Gender','DateOffBorth',
                 'MarrigeStatus', 'Religion', 'PhoneNumber', 'Nationality', 
                 'CurrentAddress', 'PernamentAddress', 'Religion', 'EducationProgram', 
                 'EducationBoard', 'NameOfInstitute', 'MySkill', 'WorkingExperience', 
                 'WorkedCompanyName', 'WorkedCompanyWebsite', 'JobCategory',
                 'Language', 'AboutMe', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Instagram',
                 'UploadCv', 'UploadProfilePicture']



    def clean_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data["__all__"]       
        return data
```

#Views.py

```
@login_required
@jobseeker_required
def JobseekerProfileCreateView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username_form = JobseekerUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = JobseekerProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = 
                                                         request.user.jobseekerprofile)
        if username_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            username_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

            messages.success(request, f'Your Accounted has been updated!')
            return redirect('../')

    else:
        username_form = JobseekerUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = JobseekerProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = 
                                                           request.user.jobseekerprofile)

    contex = {'u_form': username_form, 'p_form': profile_form }
    return render(request, 'account/Jobseeker/add_profile_detail.html' , contex)
```

#edit_Profile.html

```
<form method = 'POST'  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Add your detail in database</legend>
                        <div class = "container">
                            {{ u_form|crispy }}
                            {{ p_form|crispy }}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">Save</button>
                    </div>
  </form>
```

user profile update form(blank):

[image: 1]

Don't throw any errors while, fill required forms fields fields, all are saved successful but after refresh this page all forms fields are empty.
How to solve this it? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, in your views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile_form = JobseekerProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.jobseekerprofile)
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        request.user.username = request.POST['username']
        request.user.save()
        profile_form.save()

        messages.success(request, f'Your Accounted has been updated!')
        return redirect('/')

else:
    username_form = JobseekerUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_form = JobseekerProfileForm(instance=request.user.jobseekerprofile)
```

Comment: It works, but profile picture is not updating, how to solve it?